# Map leader command for NerdCommenter

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I am trying to do a remapping when I'm in insert mode to insert a comment but am having a tough time figuring out what all the keys map to. What I am trying to do is:

:inoremap <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> ==> <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

Basically, if I'm in insert mode I want to get out of insert mode to insert the comment (leader+c+space) and then go back into insert mode.

What would the correct `:inoremap` mapping for this be? What I have right now is:

```
:inoremap <leader>c<space> <Esc><Leader>c<space>i
```

But this doesn't seem to work (at least the latter half of it -- it does seem to be executing the mapping command). Note: the plugin I'm trying to remap is:

https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter

> `[count]<leader>c<space> |NERDCommenterToggle|`
>
> Toggles the comment state of the selected line(s). If the topmost selected line is commented, all selected lines are uncommented and vice versa.

Comment: See [double post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260136/doing-an-insert-remapping-for-commenter)

Comment: As @Zorzi helpfully reminds, cross-posting is discouraged on the SE network

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sure, which one should I post on then? It seems like SO is more active.

Comment: Eh, disagree. [so] has more traffic but is increasingly less willing to allow vim questions. [vi.se], on the other hand, is *only* for them (and a few dedicated users check the new questions practically every day, so)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts:

1. The "do one normal command in insert mode" is `<C-o>`, so you could go with (`<plug>NERDCommenterComment` is the "comment map"):

```
inoremap <Leader>c<space> <C-o><plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

But that won't work, because `noremap` prevents `<plug>` mappings from working (well it prevents all mappings on the right hand side, including `<plug>`).

2. You could then try

```
imap <Leader>c<space> <C-o><plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

3. But at this point, since you're using recursive maps, you might as well do

```
imap <Leader>c<space> <C-o><Leader>c<space>
```

But make sure you don't map `<C-o>` in insert mode.

---

P.S. If you ever have to type `<Leader>c<space>`, this mapping will get in your way... (e.g., my leader is space, although many use comma—what if you have to type that for some reason?). Recommended usage is to use normal mode for most things (like triggering commenting) and insert mode for, well, inserting things.

Comment: Ugh I ended up answering on the SO one instead... :-( But basically agreed with your answer here, use `Ctrl+O` and insert mode mappings are typically somewhat problematic. My guidance there was to learn to use `Ctrl+O` and use it directly in this case rather than creating a mapping for it.

Comment: I feel your pain :) @filbranden